# Com object method is blocking in asp.net core but not unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, com

I have a class I have used to wrap up a com object (MLApp) that is used to call into matlab. I have a unit test that initializes 5 matlab sessions and runs a command that pauses for 10 seconds in each individual session. My unit test takes ~10 seconds to run which is expected since they should be executing in parallel.

```
[Test]
public void ParallelExecution()
{
    List<MatlabRunner> runners = new List<MatlabRunner>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        runners.Add(new MatlabRunner());
    }

    try
    {
        List<Task<string>> t = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach (MatlabRunner r in runners)
             t.Add(Task.Run<string>(()=>r.Execute( "pause(10)" )));

        Task<string>.WaitAll(t.ToArray());

        t.ForEach((task) => System.Console.WriteLine(task.Result));

    }
    finally
    {
        runners.ForEach((r)=>r.Quit());
    }
}
```

However, now when I put what amounts to the same code in my asp.net core project, I can make two web requests and they are both received in parallel (I know this because I log that the request is received) but then the call into runner.Execute() is serialized.

```
[HttpGet("Verify")]
public JsonResult Verify(String lot = null,String lotStatus = null,int? NumPorts = null,int? wafer = null)
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Logs\log.txt", "\n\Received Request! " + System.DateTime.Now + "\n");

    String command = "pause(10)";
    MatlabRunner runner = null;
    String result = "";
    try
    {
      runner = new MatlabRunner();
        result = runner.Execute(command);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Logs\log.txt", e.StackTrace + " " + e.InnerException + " " + e.GetType() + e.Source + " " + e.GetBaseException());
    }
    finally
    {
        runner.Quit();
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Logs\log.txt", "\nQuit! " + System.DateTime.Now + "\n");
    }
    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

The problem is that I make two, parallel GET requests to this Verify method. While one request is calling `runner.Execute("pause(10)")` the other request is blocked from calling this method. I would expect to make two calls to this Verify method in parallel and them both to execute in parallel, finishing in a total of ~10 seconds. However, for both requests to complete takes 20 seconds (10 for the first, 10 for the second). In my unit test, I call this same method in parallel using Tasks and the entire unit test executes in 10 seconds, despite having 5 runners launched. If I were to do the same in the web service, it would take 50 seconds. Hopefully this is enough info. I can attach a log with time stamps to show how things are executing, if it would be valuable.

Am I missing something from a configuration perspective in IIS? Potentially something when I build or publish?

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what's wrong? I read it a couple of times and I cannot determine what the problem is

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sure, I have added the edit above.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clearer. I wonder how you are calling this endpoint, though?

Comment: I am making the request by opening two separate browsers and putting the URL in each.